# Removing a single line from CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV with several rows and two columns: "Name" and "Information".

I'm looping through the CSV and checking each line for a condition, if the condition is met I'd like to remove the line:

```
for ($i=0; $i -le $CSV.length; $i++)
{            
    if ($CSV.name == "Fred")
    {
         #remove $CSV[$i] -- that one line; both "Name" and "Information"
    }
}
```

I've seen solutions that use `Get-Content` or `Import-Csv` and temporary file(s) but I haven't wrapped my head around it and figure there must be an easier way.

Regardless, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would read the CSV using the `Import-CSV` cmdlet and use the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter the entries. Finally, write the CSV back using the `Export-CSV` cmdlet:

```
$csv = import-csv 'YourPath.csv'
$csv | Where Name -ne 'Fred' | Export-Csv 'YourPath.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Good approach, but I'm afraid this answer risks overwriting the file `YourPath.csv` before it is completely read.   It should either save into a new file, or read into a variable before writing.

Comment: @Burt_Harris You are right. I will adopt my script.

Comment: Looses some elegance with the temp variable.   Another way to make it a one-liner would be to put the import-csv inside parens, e.g: `(import-csv .\test.csv)|where Name -ne 'Fred'| export-csv test.csv -NoTypeInformation`